# Javascript console message not printed when in an assigned function

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have the code below. Which injects the script in head of the page correctly. But why is the "createReview called" message never printed to the developer console?

ps. I'm unsure what this construct is called technically so I just called it an "assigned function".
`MyJSObject.createReview = function (c)`

In head of page:

```
if (typeof MyJSObject === "undefined" || !MyJSObject) {var MyJSObject = {};}
MyJSObject.headLoc = document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);

MyJSObject.createReview = function (c) {
    console.error('createReview called');
    MyJSObject.widgetType = c.widgetType;
    var a = "https://www.example.com/api/getcompanyreviewdetails/?id=2&callback=MyJSObject.writeReviewsCallback";
    var b = document.createElement("script");
    b.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    b.setAttribute("src", a);
    MyJSObject.headLoc.appendChild(b);

};
```

Then on a button click I call this function, after which I'd expect the "createReview called" message to be printed to the console as an error (I use `console.error` since there's alreayd a lot of loglines created by other apps and I don't want to have to look for my message. `console.log` does not show anything either btw):

```
MyJSObject.createReview({"widgetType":1});
```

Comment: `console.log()` ?

Comment: Does the rest of the code work (i.e. does it load the file)? Does it print anything else to the console?

Comment: Well it is called for me when I run it and throws an error since `a` is not defined.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/9es7jc0b/ albeit there are other console errors. Perhaps something in the environment is causing the disruption.

Comment: See my updated post with variable `a` declared. And I do filter on errors...nothing appears. Any ideas? @TheValyreanGroup `console.error` works just like `console.log`, just prints to a different ouput window (see my post too). All suggestions are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

I does appears in your console **as an error.**  bcause it's .error not .log

Maybe you filtered your console for logs and not errors ?

BTW you have an error on this line  `b.setAttribute("src", a);` "a is undefined"

try F12 on this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9obz60rL/1/)

If filter is not the problem, and since it works for me,please try the chrome canary, this happened to me once and was solved on chrome next version.

Comment: See my updated post with variable a declared. And I do filter on errors...nothing appears. Any ideas?

Comment: @Flo updated my answer, please try canary and update us

Comment: Thanks, I tried in several other browsers (Edge, Firefox, safari) and it does not work there either. I don't think it's Chrome related, I think there's something else going on here...but what :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you properly registered a callback to the desired click event?

check that by printing out something there too

```
$('#buttonToClick').click(function(){
    console.log("Check Click");
    myJSObject.createReview(..);
});
```

If you can't find that in the Console it means you are not invoking the createReview method at all

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tried that already `console.error('switch clicked, now calling createreview');` right before I call the createReview function and that line does get printed to the console. It's strange, because also when I add a breakpoint in the Chrome dev console on lines within `createReview` it never breaks. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may try it on a different browser to see if you don't have a bug.
2. Maybe in your includes, someone overwrote console.log and console.error.
   e.g:

   `console.log = function(){//donothing}`

   In such case, you should output the function body to your dom to ensure no one altered it.
   Idem :

`document.getElementById('someJunkDiv').innerHTML = console.log.toString()`